# xcode UIAlertView on an NSTimer

Tags: ios, multithreading

I want to put an alert view on a 15 minute timer   with a YES or NO button.  This works fine if the user stays on that view. However the UIAlertView uses a local variable for its title and in the delegate method.  When the user changes views the program crashes.  Can I make a UIAlertView wait for 15 minutes then implement the delegate method?  I tried to put the delegate method in other views, but don't know how to pass the variable with the alert.  I've done a little research and think maybe with a Notification or background thread (but background threads I don't think can do UI stuff and an alert is UI)

```
- (IBAction)sendInAppMsg:(UIButton *)sender
{
    ....
    //****This is the message that calls the UIAlertView on a timer
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(pause) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void) pause
{
    UIAlertView *responseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success?" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did you reach %@  %@", self.currentDoc.firstName, self.currentDoc.lastName ] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No",  nil];
    [responseAlert show];
}


-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    //Update Parse Cloud with users response
    PFObject *contactAttempt = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ContactAttempt"];
    contactAttempt  [@"inApp"] = @"push";
    contactAttempt [@"from"] = [[PFUser currentUser] username];
    contactAttempt [@"to"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", self.currentDoc.firstName, self.currentDoc.lastName ];
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        contactAttempt  [@"response5"] =  @YES;
        [contactAttempt saveInBackground];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        contactAttempt  [@"response5"] =  @NO;
        [contactAttempt saveInBackground];
    }
}
//works fine and updates cloud with user response unless user changes views :(
```

Comment: What does the error log say when it crashes?

Comment: 2014-04-03 12:03:10.297 CDDoctors[1940:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba8dce0

Comment: Looks like your timer is firing when the view is destroyed. I thought this shouldn't happen since NSTimer should keep a strong reference to the target object, but I don't think you should be doing this to a view, nor should you have logic like this in view code either ( this is a view, not a view controller right? )

Comment: I put it in a view controller, I know my logic is not good.   So could I get a response on a timed UIAlert View another way?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(goBack:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
    ...
}

- (void)goBack {
    // Pop to previous view controller or whatever.
}

- (void)didPressButton:(id)sender {
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;
}

Comment: How would you "go back" or call the view you want?